# How do I resolve jquery-validate + bootstrap has-error conflict

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

*I'm sorry if this is an easy fix, and the wall of text but I've scoured the net and this site and found many solutions, none address my problem:*

I have a server-side validation to ensure no company exists in the DB with the same name, the request fires, and returns with the expected result of true/false and the MVC validation outputs as expected

The bootstrap and jquery validation processes the response and outputs correctly as the user is typing and any duplicates shows the correct error message.

However when the user tabs out / clicks out of the input field, validation is done again and shows success even when there is an error:

[validation status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLan9.png)

I can see that has-error and has-success change on loss of focus, I am assuming it is the bootstrap validation that is doing it as the MVC error message is still there, however the jquery.validation.definition settings should have handled that?

**Note: There are multiple forms on this page (seperated into partial views)**

I have seen different settings for the validation settings, however what I have is the closet I can get to working.... Any help is greatly appreciated.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8po19ct/10/)

libraries/frameworks

```
- .net MVC 5
- bootstrap 4 
- jquery
- jquery-validate
- jquery-validate-unobtrusive
```

site prerequisites:

web.config

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
   <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryvalidateUnobtrusive")
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
//Bootstrap
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/scripts/components/bootstrap/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/components/respond.js",
    "~/Scripts/components/vendor/validator.js"
));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
    "~/Scripts/components/jQuery/validate/jquery.validate.definition.js"
));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryvalidateUnobtrusive").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
));
```

Code:

Controller (SupportCompany.cs)

```
    public JsonResult SupportCompanyValidation(string Name)
    {
        //procedureValues = dbObject.checkDataType(supportCompany);

        var result = dbObject.SQLConnection("Select_Support_Companies", "@NAME = N'" + Name + "'");
        message = result.Item1;
        payload = result.Item2;
        bool notExists = true;

        if (payload.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            notExists = false;
        }

        return Json(notExists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Model (SupportCompany.cs)

```
    [Remote("SupportCompanyValidation", "SupportCompany", ErrorMessage = "Company name already exists")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

View (index.cshtml)

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="Name" class="col-md-4 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Name:")</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { placeholder = "Company Name", @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
        </div>
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </div>
     <label class="help-block with-errors">*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)</label>
</div>
```

jquery.validate.unobtrusive compatability settings (jquery.validate.definition.js)

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.

In my bundle I had:

```
"~/Scripts/components/vendor/validator.js"
```

This was brought in from a third party table plugin, but it conflicts with bootstrap + MVC integration.

validator.js is a bootstrap plugin found here: github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator so I'm raising the issue there.

I'm going to have to be more careful with bringing in third-party plugins and make more of my own :p